# Замена строк средствами PowerShell скрипта или bat

Tags: строки, bat, powershell

Мне было дано задание сделать portable версию одной программы с помощью PowerShell скрипта или bat. Кроме всего прочего, что я таки смог реализовать стоит задача найти и заменить в файле init.js две строки:

```
app.setPath('userData', path.join(app.getPath('appData'), app.getName()))
app.setPath('userCache', path.join(app.getPath('cache'), app.getName()))
```

на строки

```
var appProfileDir = "Profile"
for (let arg of process.argv) {
 if (arg.indexOf('--profile-dir=') === 0) {
 appProfileDir = arg.substr(arg.indexOf('=') + 1)
   }
}
var profilePath = path.join(path.dirname(process.execPath), appProfileDir)
app.setPath('userData', profilePath)
app.setPath('userCache', profilePath)
```

вот ссыль с более подробно расписанной этой штукой.
https://gist.github.com/milolav/f7a12285761db9726bce2aff11adb3af

я пытался реализовать нечто такое, но это не работает

```
 Get-Content 'E:\NuGet\WhatsAppPort\temp\browser' | ForEach-Object { 
     $_ -replace 'app.setPath(`'userData`', path.join(app.getPath(`'appData`'), 
     app.getName()))', 'var appProfileDir = `"Profile`" n for (let arg of 
     process.argv) {nif (arg.indexOf(`'--profile-dir=') === 0) {nappProfileDir= 
     arg.substr(arg.indexOf(`'=`') + 1)n}`n}' } | Out-File 
'E:\NuGet\WhatsAppPort\temp\browser'
```

@AlexanderPetrov Как вы и просили редактирую вопрос: ваш вариант, как и мой, вместо замены строк, очищает файл.
Я пытался использовать Set-Content через pipe, но это не помогло.

Comment: В программировании нет такого понятия: "не работает". Всегда есть точная ошибка парсера/компилятора/среды выполнения, точное описание желаемого и получаемого поведения кода.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, powershell выдаёт довольно внятные подсказки. Например:

> Unexpected token 'userData`'' in expression or statement.

Символ `` ` `` (backtick) используется, если нужно продолжить команду на следующей строке (чтобы не делать строки слишком длинными).
А в вашем случае нужно дублировать символ `'` (одинарная кавычка).

Кроме того, оператор `-replace` ожидает регулярное выражение, а не просто строку. Круглые скобки в регулярке означают группу. Следовательно, вам нужно их экранировать с помощью обратной наклонной черты (бэкслэша) `\`.

Также непонятно, почему вы решили, что символ `n` преобразуется в перевод строки.

В итоге код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
$_ -replace 'app.setPath\(''userData'', path.join\(app.getPath\(''appData''\), app.getName\(\)\)\)',
'var appProfileDir = "Profile"
for (let arg of process.argv) {
  if (arg.indexOf(''--profile-dir='') === 0) {
    appProfileDir = arg.substr(arg.indexOf(''='') + 1)
  }
}'
```

Можно избавиться от дублирования одинарных кавычек, если весь литерал заключить в двойные кавычки. Однако, теперь нужно дублировать двойные кавычки, если они есть внутри строки:

```
$_ -replace "app.setPath\('userData', path.join\(app.getPath\('appData'\), app.getName\(\)\)\)",
"var appProfileDir = ""Profile""
for (let arg of process.argv) {
  if (arg.indexOf('--profile-dir=') === 0) {
    appProfileDir = arg.substr(arg.indexOf('=') + 1)
 }
}"
```

Круглые скобки при этом по-прежнему нужно экранировать.

Дальше, думаю, разберётесь сами.

Кстати, чуть не забыл. Символ `.` (точка) матчит любой символ в регулярке. Соответственно, если вам нужно точное совпадение, то и этот символ нужно экранировать.

```
"app\.setPath\('userData', path\.join\(app\.getPath\('appData'\), app\.getName\(\)\)\)"
```

В итоге получается совсем громоздко. Я бы предложил отказаться от использования оператора `-replace`, т. к. регулярки в данном случае не нужны, и взять метод `Replace`.

```
$_.Replace("app.setPath('userData', path.join(app.getPath('appData'), app.getName()))",
"var appProfileDir = ""Profile""
for (let arg of process.argv) {
  if (arg.indexOf('--profile-dir=') === 0) {
    appProfileDir = arg.substr(arg.indexOf('=') + 1)
 }
}")
```

Comment: @ДанилМанмарёв - напишите это в _вопросе_, а не в комментарии.

Comment: @ДанилМанмарёв, потому что кроме Get-Content надо еще и Set сделать

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov
Как ни крути, ваш вариант, как и мой, вместо замены строк, очищает файл. И я не понимаю, почему

Comment: @Grundy
Вариант с |Set-Content пробовал, получаю ошибку: 
    Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл
используется другим процессом

Comment: @ДанилМанмарёв - я принциипиально не буду дополнять свой ответ, пока вы не отредактируете вопрос. Потому что у меня не раз так бывало: я писал ответ, топикстартер задавал кучу новых вопросов в комментариях, я изменял ответ, потом в тему заглядывали другие люди и минусовали мой ответ, потому что он уже не соответствует основному вопросу (а комментарии никто не читает).